# Save appointment to calendar automatically

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8

Ok now. I used in my app [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/microsoft.phone.tasks.saveappointmenttask%28v=vs.105%29.aspx#mainBody) library to create a task in phone calendar app.

If i use it, after i press the button to make the appointment, phone's calendar shows up and to save it i have to press the "Save" button. How can I make my app not to open calendar to save the appointment?

Answer (score 1):

You can't do that with Windows phone api. The only way to do this is to use REST API of the calendar and connect to the outlook server directly.

Comment: [Live connect REST API](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/live/hh243648.aspx)

Comment: Yep, ok then. But just to be sure, with REST API I'll create a calendar and I'll need internet on phone just to sync with outlook, right? It's no another way to use the Calendar app on the phone?

Comment: Yes, you need internet access because you should be connected to the outlook server.